# Cocos2D font rendering issue

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Observed one serious Cocos2D Font related problem

Please see this image:

[image]

In above image, fonts are not rendered proper. I used  CCLabelBMFont. How can I resolve this problem?

Code:

```
CCLabelBMFont *userName = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:PlayerNameStr  fntFile:@"MyFont.fnt"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to leave more space between the glyphs. You can change this setting in the bitmap font editor, Glyph Designer and Hiero both have it. In Glyph Designer the setting is called Spacing and set to 2. I'm guessing you're using Hiero which has this spacing set to 0 by default.